# POSIX thread exit/crash/exception-crash while holding mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

Is there a well defined behavior for POSIX mutex ownership in case of

1. Thread exits
2. Thread crashes
3. Thread crashes due to exception

Suppose thread-1 owns a mutex. And thread-2 is waiting to acquire the same mutex. And thread-1 goes the 1/2/3 scenario. What is the effect on thread-2 ?

PS : I believe the behavior for spin-lock is, NOT to unblock thread-2, with reasoning that the section protected by spin-lock is in bad shape anyways.

Comment: it remains locked. This is c, so the runtime doesn't do anything for you, so if you don't unlock it yourself it stays locked.

Answer (score 8):

If you're worried about these issues, *Robust Mutexes* may be the tool you're looking for:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html

After a thread that owns a robust mutex terminates without unlocking it, the next thread that attempts to lock it will get `EOWNERDEAD` and become the new owner. This signals that it's responsible for cleaning up the state the mutex protects, and marking it consistent again with the `pthread_mutex_consistent` function before unlocking it. Unlocking it without marking it consistent puts the mutex in a permanently unrecoverable state.

Note that with robust mutexes, all code that locks the mutex must be aware of the possibility that `EOWNERDEAD` could be returned.

Comment: But be extra careful when `EOWNERDEAD` is returned -- any data structures protected by the mutex will likely be in an inconsistent state.  See [Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/12/463977.aspx) for a more detailed discussion (although that refers to Windows mutexes, which have slightly different semantics from pthreads mutexes, but the main points of the post still hold).

Comment: Also, note that the documentation says that "If the owning thread of a robust mutex terminates while holding the mutex lock, the next thread that acquires the mutex **may** be notified about the termination by the return value [EOWNERDEAD]" (emphasis mine) -- it is not *guaranteed* to return `EOWNERDEAD`.  Only in the case of when the *process* holding the mutex is terminated does it say that it *shall* return `EOWNERDEAD` (in which case it would have to be a process-shared mutex).

Comment: Thank you for your second comment. That's a really important detail I was not aware of. It's also worth noting that an implementation is not even required to support the robust attribute for non-process-shared mutexes.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple. If you don't explicitly unlock the mutex, it remains locked, regardless of what happened or why. This is c, not ruby on rails or visual basic.

Comment: I dont think so. Windows definitely does some clean-up in case 1 and case 3.

Comment: Perhaps Kevin should have said "This is POSIX, not Windows."

Comment: The closest equivalent to a posix mutex on windows is a CRITICAL_SECTION. The MSDN page says "If a thread terminates while it has ownership of a critical section, the state of the critical section is undefined."