# Will killed process/thread release mutex?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex, apc

Several processes access shared memory, locking it with the mutex and `pthread_mutex_lock()` for synchronization, and each process can be killed at any moment (in fact I described `php-fpm` with `APC` extension, but it doesn't matter).
Will the mutex be unlocked automatically, if the process locked the mutex and then was killed?
Or is there a way to unlock it automatically?

**Edit:** As it turns out, dying processes and threads have similar behavior in this situation, which depends on [robust attribute of mutex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html).

Comment: It depends on the type of mutex being used, which you didn't specify. Punch [robust mutex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html) into your favorite search engine.

Comment: Please see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348465/posix-thread-exit-crash-exception-crash-while-holding-mutex) and as David said look into robust mutexes. They don't get unlocked after a crash, but the next thread that will attempt to lock it will receive a `EOWNERDEAD` error code.

Comment: It would be nice to make an answer out of that, but David's comment is probably too terse to be an answer as-is.

Comment: I'd consider this question being a duplicate to the question linked by *Cicada*'s comment. It's been answered by you there? @R..

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, thank you, robust mutexes is what I looked for.

Comment: @Cicada, I thought, that dying processes and threads should behave differently, so I didn't read this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the type of mutex. A "robust" mutex will survive the death of the thread/process. See this question: [POSIX thread exit/crash/exception-crash while holding mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348465/posix-thread-exit-crash-exception-crash-while-holding-mutex)

The next thread that will attempt to lock it will receive a `EOWNERDEAD` error code

Note: Collected information from the comments.